# the problem is in getPublicnid function where Undefined array key 0 is returning as the value is not given yet

Tags: php

```
function getPublicnid($nid){
    $query ="select r.*,p.name as 'p_name',p.nid as 'p_nid',p.gender as 'p_gender',p.address as 'p_address',p.occupation as 'p_occupation',
    p.center as 'p_center' from reg_status r left join publicreg p on r.p_id = p.nid WHERE p_id =$nid";
    
    $rs = get($query);
    return $rs[0];
    
}


function get($query) { // for running select queries
    global $db_server,$db_uname,$db_pass,$db_name;
    $conn = mysqli_connect($db_server,$db_uname,$db_pass,$db_name);
    $data = array();
    if($conn){
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $data[] = $row;
        }
    }
    return $data;

}
```

Warning: Undefined array key 0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\practice\FinalProject\controllers\publicController.php on line 334

Comment: Perhaps `$rs` is empty, which would mean your query returned no results. You'll have to do some troubleshooting to find out if that's the case, and why.

Comment: Yeah $rs is empty as query returned no value but from my point only admin can add the values. But for now i want to show validation for this problem.